# Specifying Conditions on Nested Eager Loaded Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, eager-loading

[ActiveRecord querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) has a section on Specifying Conditions on Eager Loaded Associations. Specifically, section 13.2.

According to it I can do the following:

```
Article.includes(:comments).where(comments: { visible: true })
```

What if I wanted to do something like this...

```
Article.where(param: "this").includes(user: [:comments]).where(comments: { text: "wow" })
```

Of course, the above doesn't work, I would love to be able to achieve that with some query.

As it stands, after my query I do a `articles[3].user.comments.select { |comment| comment.text == "wow" }`

Anyway to achieve the above?

Comment: Can you try this `Article.includes(user: [:comments]).where(id: 3, comments: { text: "wow" })`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need eager loading to select comments from a single article (as I understood you are trying to do this).

For given article

```
@article = Article.first
```

You can query all comments with text 'wow' using table joining

```
@comments = @article.comments.where(text: 'wow')
```